# Google Chrome loads site left aligned then after a few seconds it's normal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So I'm working on my web design company website and I'm having a glitch that only happens on Google Chrome.

Glitch

- When you load any page on my website

sneakypandastudios.com

right in the beginning for a few seconds some elements are loaded left aligned then it transitions to it's normal position. It's makings for really unclean transitions from page to page and I really need it fixed.

I think it has to do with Javascript because If I disable it on my website all the elements are displayed in the wrong position before the normal transition. I really need help with this so if anyone can help me you will be amazing!!

Thanks so much.

Glitch Example

[image: Glitch Example]

Normal Load Look

[image: Normal Load Look]

Comment: The likely cause is another plugin.JS on the page changing the layout/DOM. The clue is that it stays "wrong" with no JS running. You could start by disabling each plugin in turn and see which one moves the page. Then you need to work out how the page needs to be styled to look "correct" before that plugin fires (e.g. with it disabled).

Comment: The weird part is the glitch didn't start happening till after I linked my domain to it. At first I thought it was with my domain forwarding company so I switched it and now it's still happening. And sometimes it does it, other times it doesn't.

I honestly don't know much .JS... I'm just a self-taught beginner :/

Comment: The code is a mess. You use style tags, in-line styles and external css for the same content. I think that the layout could also change as the styles are applied due to these mixes. Please consider a clean-up.

Comment: Yes I know they're, unfortunately I don't have any control over the style tags as that all has to do with Webydo. It's a code free studio for Designers like myself to make responsive websites.

Comment: Okay guys I fixed it! It had to do with the google analytic on my site. Once I took it off and removed all the code and .js it went away. I didnt know that analytics affects load times like that so much...

Comment: It is a good practice to place your scrips at the end, right before closing the body tag. When the parser encounters a script, the site will stop loading until the scripts have finished downloading and some executing. The problem is not the usage of google analytic, because if other scripts will be added, they will affect the page load time and the flicker will appear again. My proposal is that, if you have access to your external css file, use same width, left and right properties of .mainShape25 as used in the corresponding inline style. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjWeXY

Comment: Thanks for your help and knowledge Kris! I really appreciate it :) I'm slowly starting to learn. Mostly from trial and error haha